# Can I Recover The Files in the Directory /usr from a btrfs Snapshot?

Tags: partitioning, xubuntu, data-recovery, btrfs, snapshot

Some time ago, I moved the folder `/usr` to its own partition. 
Before this it had lived in the `/` partition which has a **btrfs** filesystem.

Accidentally, I formatted my `/usr` partition from my Windows XP OS.

Using an Xubuntu LiveCD, I can see there are three **snapshots**, two of which contain my old `/usr`.

I am wondering if I can recover my `/usr` from the snapshots taken by btrfs?

Can I just copy the contents of the snapshot to `/usr`?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Btrfs and the good snapshots (at least it looks good to me, CoW snapshot of the whole /)

You need to mount the snapshot (it works just like a subvolume) and they copy the files over properly (using `rysnc`)

Steps (I recommend doing this from a Live DVD/USB system):

1. mount the snapshot to a temporary mount point, for example `/mnt/snapshot`

`mount -t btrfs -o subvol=apt-snapshot-xxx block_device /mnt/snapshot`

1. then you'll be able to access the contents, old /usr should be under `/mnt/snapshot/usr`
2. mount your `/usr` to a temporary location, for example `/mnt/usr`
3. Copy the contents over (be careful with the trailing / of source) from snapshot to your current `/usr`

`sudo rsync -axHAX --progress /mnt/snapshot/usr/ /mnt/usr`

Reboot and it should be good.